OpenUI5 Cordova Libraries Setup
I'm trying to upgrade my openui5 libraries on my cordova app. I downloaded the new version 1.122.1 and put the files in www/openui5-runtime-1.122.1/resources and setup like so:
<script src="openui5-runtime-mobile-1.122.1/resources/sap-ui-core.js"  
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_horizon"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"":"./"}'
        >
        </script>

When I compile and try and run my app I'm always getting that it sap.ui.getCore is not valid. If I switch back to my old version....which is like 1.28 then it all works fine. Not sure why it seems to have issues with the sap.ui.getCore stuff

What is the result of the openui5-runtime-mobile-1.122.1/resources/sap-ui-core.js? Is it really the same as the one from https://sdk.openui5.org/1.122.1/resources/sap-ui-core.js? Or what is the difference? Are you accessing sap.ui.getCore() before the sap-ui-bootstrap script? Any async or defer attribute? Please share the entire HTML or any other steps to reproduce the issue.
